# Swift: White space when hiding tab bar in same view controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I am having TabBar in my ViewController. I want to show side menu view when, side menu button clicked. I am animating the view from right to left. Works fine. But, while doing like this, tab bar hides bottom part of side menu's view. So I tried to hide the tab bar. But, still white space is there. I dont know how to remove that white space. I have used constraints for side menu view. Kindly guide me.

I am facing this white space issue, when we tried to hide tab bar in same view controller.

Kindly guide me.

**My Code**

```
 @IBAction func sideMenu_Acn(sender: UIButton) {
self.SM_left_Constrain.constant = 0

tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: How did you set your constraints ?

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide a *lot* more information. There's little chance of helping you without knowing what you've tried. With the currebt level of detail, the most detailed response we can possibly give is, "you must be doing it wrong."  Help us help you.

Comment: TRAILING , LEAD, BOTTOM = 0
TOP = 34   @DejanSkledar

Comment: yes   @JoshuaNozzi ... I have edited my code.